# Not able to Save the HTTPPOST2 response in the data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, httppost

I have made a HTTPPOST2 API call and got the JSON response. I want to insert the JJSON response into Data Extension. Below is the JSON response :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "activationId": "XXXX",
    "restrictedToCustomer": false,
    "coupon": {
        "barcode": "XXXX",
        "serialNumber": "XXX",
        "couponRangeId": "XX",
        "createdAt": "XX",
        "customerReference": null,
        "status": "Active",
        "validFrom": null,
        "validTo": "XX"
    }
}
```

I want to insert the Coupon section in the Data extension. Thanks for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonVariable);

if (json) {

    var coupon = json.coupon;

    for(var j = 0; j < coupon.length; j++) {

        var barCode = coupon[j][barcode];
        var serialNumber = coupon[j][serialNumber];
        var couponid = Platform.Function.GUID(); // and so forth

        //Assuming you don't have any coupon id in your json
        Platform.Function.Upsert("CouponDE","CouponID",couponid,"barcode",barCode,"serialNumber",serialNumber)

    }

}
```

Hope it helps :)